# When do I need object files for linkage of shared library?

Tags: c++, linker

I just asked "[Dependency injection in shared library, does the lib need object files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39807617/dependency-injection-in-shared-library-does-the-lib-need-object-files)". This is a pretty specific case, but I'd rather like to learn when linkers need object files in general.

Is there a deterministic way to tell if the linkage of a shared object needs object files of used classes or not?  (Meant is the g++ linkage stage after the compilation of the library, not the OS linkage at runtime)

Comment: Um, certain object files (sometimes packed into .a files) are always needed, although at times those object files set up the dynamic linking dependency needed.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: What did I miss? What is unclear?